# Time complexity for: do all paths between node A and node B intersect either node X or node Y?

Tags: time-complexity

If I have a graph with at least 4 nodes, what would be the minimum time complexity for this?

Note:  I'm not a computer scientist, I'm a phd student in philosophy, so I apologize for my ignorance in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm: remove nodes X and Y from the graph, and then see if A and B are still connected. You can see whether the nodes are still connected using breadth-first search from A and see whether you get to B. Time complexity of removing X and Y is constant O(1) and time complexity of breadth-first search is O(E + V) which is considered "linear" for graphs. Overall complexity would thus be "linear" for general graphs.